# Regexp: Catch anything after and including capital letter and before a digit?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Test strings:

```
TEST Hello, world, 75793250
TEST TESTER Hello, world. Another word here. 75793250
```

Desired match:

```
Hello, world, 
Hello, world. Another word here.
```

I want to select everything between the capital lettered words and a 8 digit number.

How can I do this?

EDIT: The purpose is to clean up a large text file using Notepad++. I am using both Notepad++ and [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
\b[A-Z]+\b\s+(.*)\d{8}
```

Revised to exclude the capitalized word at the beginning. The sought text is in capture-group 1:

```
(?:\b[A-Z]+\b\s+)+(.*)\d{8}
```

If the capitalized words (the markers) are only at the beginning of the line:

```
^(?:\b[A-Z]+\b\s+)+(.*)\d{8}
```

Comment: @Jack Sorry I don't quite follow(?). There may be more than one capitalized word, but only the last one is the *marker* that begins the capture, according to the OPs description.

Comment: If you're not using multiline mode, this will match `Hello, world, 75793250
TEST TESTER Hello, world. Another word here.`.

Comment: Thanks Andy G, however using http://rubular.com/ and Notepad++ it matches the whole line. I only want it to match the middle part. Please revise.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
/(?<=[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*\b)(?:(?!\b\d{8}).)*/
```

Basically:

- look behind for all caps or space followed by a word break.
- then start match, and from that point, match until you run into a word break followed by 8 digits.

---

If your regex engine complains (like mine) about variable length look behinds, try this instead:

```
/(?:[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*\b)((?:(?!\b\d{8}).)*)/
```

Yields:

```
>> "TEST Hello, world, 75793250".match /(?:[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*\b)((?:(?!\b\d{8}).)*)/
=> #<MatchData "TEST Hello, world, " 1:" Hello, world, ">

>> "TEST TESTER Hello, world. Another word here. 75793250".match /(?:[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*\b)((?:(?!\b\d{8}).)*)/
=> #<MatchData "TEST TESTER Hello, world. Another word here. " 1:" Hello, world. Another word here. ">
```

Comment: Thanks Denis, this almost works. I am using http://rubular.com/ to test. However it seem to catch the first capital letter part. `(?=[A-Z ]*\b)(?:(?!\d).)*` If I add the slashes it complains that I need to escape forward slashes. If I do : `\/(?=[A-Z ]*\b)(?:(?!\d).)*\/`I get "no matches".

Comment: I've fixed the regex, and updated the answer with another one that worked in irb.

Comment: `(?:[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*\b)((?:(?!\b\d{8}).)*)` matches everything before the numbers. If you can find a solution on rubular.com I would be very happy. :) rubular.com seems to be 100% compatible with Notepad++

Comment: See the output I posted: there are two groups. The first is the entire match; the second is the sub-match, which is the part that you want. In ruby, access it like `"TEST Hello, world, 75793250".match(/(?:[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*\b)((?:(?!\b\d{8}).)*)/)[1]`. The first regex (`/(?<=[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*\b)(?:(?!\b\d{8}).)*/`) might work as is in notepad++. I'm on a mac, so can't test if which regex flavor it uses. :-)

Comment: The first regexp throws an error I am affraid. I will take a look at how I can remove the match groups in Notepad++. As you say the groups are correct.

Comment: @Kaah: In ruby, probably other regex flavors, the first expression raises a syntax error because the lookbehind is of variable length. Not all regex flavors support that feature. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java code below:

```
    String str = "TEST TESTER Hello, world. Another word here. 75793250";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(([A-Z]+\\s)+)([^\n]*)([0-9]{8})");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a character class to create an atom that matches just upper case letters - `[A-Z]`. Then you want to match that multiple times (at least once?), so `[A-Z]+`.

Then you want to catch likely anything - `.+`, but you want to capture it so wrap it in a named capture - `(?<nameHere>.+)`.

Then you want to match the numbers to bookend the capture with the digits, so that the digits won't end up in the capture (since `.+` matches anything). `\d` is the digit character class shortcut, and we want one or more digits, so `\d+`.

Put it all together, looking for whitespace (`\s`) in between everything:

```
[A-Z]+\s+(?<nameHere>.+)\s+\d+
```

Pull the named capture out using the Match class - `Match.Captures`.